# PHP Regular Expression Ignore Negative Numbers in String

Tags: php, regex

I've looked all over the place, but I can't seem to only return the first positive, real number. So far, I have successfully found how to find the first positive or negative number and also only find the first negative number. Below are the two I did correctly and the one I can't get.

```
$str1 = "-ABS-.-179.3333es-k15dk825.44f";
```

1. Find first real number in string:

   preg_match("/-?((.\d+)|(\d+(.\d+)?))/", $str1, $matches) // <- GOOD!
   Expected output: -179.3333
   Actual output: -179.3333
2. Find first, negative real number in string:

   preg_match("/-((.\d+)|(\d+(.\d+)?))/", $str1, $matches) // <- GOOD!
   Expected output: -179.3333
   Actual output: -179.3333
3. Find first, positive real number in string:

   preg_match("/(?<!-)((.\d+)|(\d+(.\d+)?))/", $str1, $matches) //<- WRONG!
   Expected output: 15
   Actual output: 79.3333

Comment: add some input and expected output also with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and see if it does what you want.

```
preg_match_all('/[^\-\d\.]((?:\d+)(?:(?:\.\d+)|(?:\d+)))/', $str1, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for:

```
preg_match('/(?<!-|\d|\.)\d+/', $str1, $matches);
```

**Update**

How's about:

```
preg_match('/(?<!-|\d|\.)\d+(\.\d+)?/', $str1, $regs);
```

Comment: Very close. I get back 15 and 825, instead of 15 and 825.44. It knows not to include any real, negative numbers, but only returns positive integers. Hmmm....

Comment: this would work, except that it doesn't recognize any positive number that starts with a decimal point, ie. .1, .99, .052 etc.